# Can't get Wordpress index added to Magento results

Tags: wordpress, magento, algolia

Having some issues getting algolia to add an index - main index is Magento , trying to add wordpress.

Everything is configured , followed instructions here https://community.algolia.com/magento/doc/m1/external-autocomplete-source/ .  I used the boilerplate extension to override the default magento search and it works fine.

However , it errors when it gets to the following line

var customTemplate = $('#autocomplete_wordpress_template').html();

( I changed the  template name to my one .. and I get the following error )

Everything is wired up correctly I think , I can see the script block with is="autocomplete_wordpress_template" in the source HTML , and I got the extension working as a custom extension with just magento on it's own.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null
    at algoliaHookBeforeAutocompleteStart (autocomplete.js:118)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (autocomplete.js:84)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:370)
    at ge.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (autocomplete.js:63)
    at u (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
    at ge.fn.init.ge.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
    at ge.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
    at Object.ge [as $] (jquery.js:75)
```

Comment: It looks like the template with ID `autocomplete_wordpress_template` is not rendered to the page.
Can you check that all the template from your custom extension are rendered to the page?

Comment: This script is in the page.  I can see it in the page source.

    <script type="text/template" id="autocomplete_wordpress_template">
        <a class="algoliasearch-autocomplete-hit" href="{{url}}">
            <div class="info-without-thumb">
                {{{_highlightResult.value.value}}}
            </div>
        </a>
    </script>

Comment: That's weird. Would you mind sharing with me an URL to live website where I could see that?

Comment: www.returntohealth.nz

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website and for some reason `$` is not assigned to jQuery function.

When I replaced `$` for `jQuery` when you fetch the HTML of the template, it started to work:

[image]

So try to replace `$` by `jQuery` and it should work just fine. And you'll most probably have to change it on the line 122 as well:

`source: jQuery.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(customIndex, customIndexOptions), ...`